# WebView: закрывать и открывать Zoom-инструментарий

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, webview, android-viewpager

Имеется `ViewPager` с 2-мя вкладками (фрагментами). В одной из них `WebView`. Если туда кликнуть, то появляется Zooming и так и должно быть. Но вот если после этого поменять вкладку, то он остается висеть ни к селу ни к городу. Как его закрыть? И как узнать когда закрыть, то есть как узнать, что фрагмент спрятался?
Вот так настроена вьюшка:

```
graphWebView = (WebView) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings settings = graphWebView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
graphWebView.setInitialScale(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отследить когда скрывать/показывать zoom можете установить `OnPageChangeListener` на `ViewPager` и в его методе `onPageSelected(int position)` менять состояние.

Чтобы скрыть zoom контролы используйте метод `myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);`.